How can I reverse the output of my program?
Whenever I input 5 I get
12345
1234
123
12
1
but I need the output to be 544333222211111 how can I fix my code
program BigNumbers;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );

static
n: int8;

begin BigNumbers;
stdout.put( "Gimme a decimal value to use for n: ");
stdin.get( n );

mov(n, AL);  // Move the value of n to AL

// Outer loop to go from 0 to n
ForLP:
cmp(AL, 0);      // Compare AL with 0
jle EndForLP;    // If AL <= 0, jump to EndForLP

mov(1, BL);     // Initialize BL to 1 instead of 0

// Inner loop to print numbers from 1 to AL
InnerLP:
cmp(BL, AL);     // Compare BL with AL
jg EndInnerLP;   // If BL > AL, jump to EndInnerLP
stdout.puti8( BL ); // Print the value in BL
inc(BL);         // Increment BL
jmp InnerLP;     // Jump back to InnerLP

EndInnerLP:
stdout.put ( nl ); // Print a new line
dec( AL );       // Decrement AL
jmp ForLP;       // Jump back to ForLP

EndForLP:

end BigNumbers;


Iv'e tried changing the structure of the loops but I keep getting errors.

First of all, sit down with a pencil and some paper. Try to create a high-level algorithm for the problem. Then if you know C or other similar language, implement the algorithm in that. And once that works, implement it in HLA.
